# Weird behavior of recursive class in for loop

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains a vector of pointers to objects of the same class.

```
class a {
public:
    std::vector<a *> children;
};
```

With this variable declaration,

```
a *v = &a();
```

the following statements can be executed repeatedly without error.

```
(*v).children.push_back(&a()); //add a child to "v"
v = (*v).children[0]; //set "v" to the newly created child
```

If the above code is placed inside a for loop, it fails during the second iteration. Specifically, it fails to push back a new "a" pointer to children, so the children vector remains empty, and a "vector subscript out of range" error is returned. Below is a minimum working example.

```
#include <vector>

class a {
public:
    std::vector<a *> children;
};

int main() {
    a *v = &a();

    (*v).children.push_back(&a());
    v = (*v).children[0];

    (*v).children.push_back(&a());
    v = (*v).children[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        (*v).children.push_back(&a());
        v = (*v).children[0];
    }
}
```

Irrespective of how many times the statements are repeated before the loop, the above program always fails during the second iteration of the loop. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Keeping the pointer to a temporary object is the culprit here. The difference within the loop comes from the fact that the loop operates on the stack, so the temporary object, that was previously still there (just because there was nothing else written over it) gets overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a *v = &a();` takes the address of a temporary value. NEVER DO THIS.
Instead, use `new` to allocate an `a` on the heap:

```
a *v = new a();
v->children.push_back(new a());
```

Note that you have lost any references to the original `v` as you keep reassigning it. This is a memory leak.